# 2nd parameter of useCallback hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Many React hooks have 2nd parameter that the hook is dependant on.

1. Is omitting the 2nd parameter the same as supplying an empty array?
2. What's the use of supplying useState function such as `setFoo` rather than a variable?

   ```
      const [foo, setFoo] = useState('')

      const cb = useCallback(() => {
      // do somethin
      }, [setFoo])
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is omitting the 2nd parameter the same as supplying an empty array?

No, not at all.

Hooks are called each render, but depending on the values of the dependencies will recompute or invoke their callback. Specifying an empty array guarantees the hook will be called once, and never again, akin to the class-based component's `componentDidMount` lifecycle function. Omitting the dependency array altogether, however, will simply call the effect each render.

For something like `useCallback` this would completely negate the purpose of memoizing a callback function as each render cycle would receive a new callback reference.

> What's the use of supplying useState function such as `setFoo`

To provide a stable callback reference that presumably calls the state setter. But this doesn't make much sense as [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) is essentially this:

```
const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
  () => {
    doSomething(a, b);
  },
  [a, b],
);
```

> **Note**
>
> The array of dependencies is not passed as arguments to the callback.
>   Conceptually, though, that’s what they represent: every value
>   referenced inside the callback should also appear in the dependencies
>   array. In the future, a sufficiently advanced compiler could create
>   this array automatically.

The useState setter isn't a stable function reference, which means each render cycle it is redefined which means any memoized callback is also recomputed. If the setter is being used by the component then just use it.

Declaring a function in the dependency array really only makes sense if it was passed to the component *as a callback*.

Comment: `Passing a function really only makes sense if it then also getting passed on as a callback.`  can you clarify this little bit?

Comment: @eugene Yes, I suppose this statement is a bit unclear if unfamiliar with hooks. The `useState` setter isn't a stable function reference, which means each render cycle it is redefined which means any memoized callback is also recomputed. If the setter is being used by the component then just use it. I'll update answer.